# How to make a color picker in Jupyter?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets, jupyter-lab

Jupyter notebooks support this color picking widget:

```
widgets.ColorPicker(
    concise=False,
    description='Pick a color',
    value='blue',
    disabled=False
)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

But instead of this, I would like to chose colors dynamically with my mouse via a 2D pane of colors:

[image]

Comment: Hello, is there anybody out there?

Comment: Just nod if you can hear me

Answer (score 1):

By clicking on the color square, you already get access to this 2D pane of colors that you can pick from.
[See the output in ipywidgets documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOTfR.png)

If you need another color picker, you can easily implement your own widget by completing the [first-widget](https://github.com/ocoudray/first-widget) (easy way to build your widgets), but it might not be worth it.